# Summing up total amount from multiple models in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The title of my question has said it all. I have multiple models, and I want to add up the amount to derive the total amount, here's my code

```
class FurnitureItem(models.Model):
    fur_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    fur_price = models.FloatField()
    fur_discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    fur_pictures =  models.ImageField(upload_to='Pictures/', blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES_CHOICES, max_length=24)
    fur_descriptions = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fur_title

        
class FurnitureOrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fur_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(FurnitureItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.fur_title}"
    ....
    
    def get_final_fur_price(self):
        if self.item.fur_discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discount_fur_price()
        return self.get_total_item_fur_price()

    
class FurnitureOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fur_items = models.ManyToManyField(FurnitureOrderItem)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_created = models.DateTimeField()
    fur_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total_fur_everything(self):
        total = 0
        for fur_order_item in self.fur_items.all():
            total += fur_order_item.get_final_fur_price()
        return total



class GraphicItem(models.Model):
    graphic_title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    graphic_price = models.FloatField()
    graphic_discount_price = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    graphic_pictures =  models.ImageField(upload_to='Pictures/', blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(choices=LABEL_CHOICES, max_length=1)
    category = models.CharField(choices=CATEGORIES_CHOICES, max_length=24)
    graphic_descriptions = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.graphic_title
    
    
class GraphicOrderItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    graphic_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    item = models.ForeignKey(GraphicItem, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.quantity} of {self.item.graphic_title}"

    ....

    def get_final_graphic_price(self):
        if self.item.graphic_discount_price:
            return self.get_total_discount_graphic_price()
        return self.get_total_item_graphic_price()

    
class GraphicOrder(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    graphic_items = models.ManyToManyField(GraphicOrderItem)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered_created = models.DateTimeField()
    graphic_ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_total_graphic_everything(self):
        total = 0
        for graphic_order_item in self.graphic_items.all():
            total += graphic_order_item.get_final_graphic_price()
        return total
```

what i've tried as regards summing up the amount for furniture and graphics

```
class TotalAmount(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    graphic_items = models.ManyToManyField(GraphicOrderItem)
    fur_items = models.ManyToManyField(FurnitureOrderItem)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def amount(self):
        return self.graphic_items.get_total_graphic_everything() + self.fur_items.get_total_fur_everything()
```

Then my views goes this way:

```
class Summary(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            fur_order = FurnitureOrder.objects.get(user=self.request.user, fur_ordered=False)
            graphic_order = GraphicOrder.objects.get(user=self.request.user, graphic_ordered=False)
            amount = TotalAmount.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
            
            context = {
            'fur_order':fur_order,'graphic_order':graphic_order,'amount':amount}
            return render(self.request, 'business/home-order-summary.html', context)
```

Thanks for your time, I no the code is lengthy, but I wanted to expanciate better.

Comment: Looks like you posted a solution. Is this code not working?

Comment: @Alex Vyushkov, I'm yet to find out because I tried passing my amount into my template yet I get a blank page. Here's what I did in my template :```{ %for amount in amount%} {{amount.amount}} {%endfor%}``` but nothing seems to be displayed on my template (web browser)

Comment: The `get` function in `Summary` doesn't look right; `try` without `except` is invalid. Perhaps delete `try` while you are debugging this issue?

Comment: @Alex Vyushkov, from what I could understand, you said I should do away with the get function right? If I'm not disturbing, can you please do a little illustration? I'll be deeply grateful. Thanks

Comment: @Alex Vyushkov, I now understand what you mean, but the get function houses self as an argument, that's why in my try statement, you could see something like ```fur_order = FurnitureOrder.objects.get(user=self.request.user, fur_ordered=False)
            graphic_order = GraphicOrder.objects.get(user=self.request.user, graphic_ordered=False)```. Thanks, any idea will be welcomed